# Does "Filtering Incoming Serialization Data" planned for Java 9 solve data deserialisation security vulnerabilities?

Tags: java, security, deserialization, owasp, java-9

I've been browsing new features of Java 9 and found this:
[JEP 290: Filter Incoming Serialization Data](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/290)
And according to another article, there is a security issue with deserialisation data in java:
[Deserialization of untrusted data](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Deserialization_of_untrusted_data)

Based on text from first article, I have reason to belive that this is feedback for problem from second article, but I'm not really sure. Is this bug still a thing for Java? And if yes, does new Java fully solves that problem?

Comment: I'm not sufficiently qualified to fully answer your question but as I understand JEP 290 the application developer will have to implement the filtering. So the question should be "Is the API powerful enough to give developers the chance to fix deserialization vulnerabilities.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, Deserialization of untrusted data is not a bug of Java, as you described it.

The vulnerability is introduced when application developers/architects design their apps in such a way that serialized data coming from untrusted sources are getting deserialized by the application without validation.

What is important to understand is that this vulnerability is introduced by bad application design.

JEP 290 allows a developer and/or a security engineer to validate the data before they get deserialized. Serialization Filtering, if done correctly, could help mitigate some deserialization attacks but does not solve the problem completely and it is very complex to configure and deploy at scale.

You can read a detailed evaluation of the Serialization Filtering feature here: https://dzone.com/articles/a-first-look-into-javas-new-serialization-filterin

To understand better the deserialization vulnerability and how you can protect your apps you can read more here: https://dzone.com/articles/why-runtime-compartmentalization-is-the-most-compr

Comment: This is simply untrue. A class with a rogue `readObject()` or `readResolve()` method can cause unwanted behaviour without any application design error whatsoever. No amount of validation will prevent that, as by the time the application gets the object it is already too late. This is *why* the feature is being introduced. NB Both your links point to the same place.

Comment: The bad design comes from the fact that the app allows deserialization of data from untrusted sources. This is a bad design decision. The vulnerability is called "Deserialization of Untrusted Data" to reflect exactly that. Even if you add validation using "Serialization Filtering" you will still be vulnerable because white/black listing have major limitations that can be bypassed. According to CERT the recommended way to solve the problem is to **rearchitect/redesign** the application. This confirms that this is a design problem. Validation is a good first step but does not solve the problem.

Comment: NB The links point to 2 separate articles that I wrote on the subject.